# django - Redirecting page if user logins for first time

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to redirect to a page that has already been made (`clientsetup`) if the user is registering to the website for the first time. Here is how the code looks like in my `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms.client_setup import ClientSetupForm
from .forms.podcast_setup import PodcastSetupForm
from .forms.episode_info import EpisodeInfoForm
from .forms.image_files import EpisodeImageFilesForm
from .forms.wordpress_info import WordpressInfoForm
from .forms.chapter_marks import ChapterMarksForm
from .forms.show_links import ShowLinksForm
from .forms.tweetables import TweetablesForm
from .forms.clicktotweet import ClickToTweetForm
from .forms.schedule import ScheduleForm

from producer.models import Client, Production, ChapterMark, ProductionLink, ProductionTweet, Podcast

from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def dashboard(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated():

        client = Client.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()

        if client is None:

                form = ClientSetupForm(request.POST or None)

                if form.is_valid():

                    instance = form.save(commit=False)
                    company_name = form.cleaned_data.get("company_name")
                    first_name = form.cleaned_data.get("first_name")
                    last_name = form.cleaned_data.get("last_name")

                    instance.company_name = company_name
                    instance.first_name = first_name
                    instance.last_name = last_name

                    instance.user = request.user

                    instance.save()

                    return render(request, "pod_funnel/forms.html")
        else:
                podcast = Podcast.objects.filter(client=client).first()

                if queryset.is_valid():

                    queryset = Client.objects.all()  # .filter(full_name__iexact="test3")
                    # print(Client.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp').filter(full_name__iexact="test3").count())
                    context = {
                        "queryset": queryset
                    }

                    return render(request, "pod_funnel/dashboard.html", context)
    return render(request, "pod_funnel/dashboard.html")

def clientsetup(request):

    title = 'Client Setup'
    title_align_center = True
    form = ClientSetupForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        "title": title,
        "form": form
    }

    if form.is_valid():

        instance = form.save(commit=False)

        company_name = form.cleaned_data.get("company_name")
        first_name = form.cleaned_data.get("first_name")
        last_name = form.cleaned_data.get("last_name")

        instance.company_name = company_name
        instance.first_name = first_name
        instance.last_name = last_name

        instance.user = request.user

        instance.save()

        return render(request, "pod_funnel/forms.html", context)

    else:

        return render(request, "pod_funnel/forms.html", context)


def podcastsetup(request):

    title = 'Podcast Setup'
    title_align_center = True
    form = PodcastSetupForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        "title": title,
        "form": form
    }

    if form.is_valid():

        instance = form.save(commit=False)

        name = form.cleaned_data.get("name")
        itunes_url = form.cleaned_data.get("itunes_url")
        client = form.cleaned_data.get("client")

        instance.name = name
        instance.itunes_url = itunes_url

        instance.client = client

        # instance.user = request.user

        instance.save()

        return render(request, "pod_funnel/forms_podcast_setup.html", context)

    else:

        return render(request, "pod_funnel/forms_podcast_setup.html", context)
```

The issue that I am having is that it still sends me straight to `dashboard` if you login for the first time and I want it to take to `clientsetup`, then go back to `dashboard` when everything is done there.

Normally you would enter straight to `dashboard` when you register or login and guide yourself from there but just want to make it more easier for somebody who is arriving for the first time.

I also added the same instances from my `clientsetup` to the `if` statement inside `dashboard`.

Would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: In your dashboard view, you have written if user is authenticate then do something, but if it is not then you are rendering dashboard template, Is this the problem ?

Comment: @Anurag Yes, I just want the dashboard rendered when the person already has setup his `client` and `podcast`. Other than that, it has to go straight to the setup so they can complete it and use the website properly.